# ios remote sometimes defaults to native music player instead of my app

Tags: iphone, ios

About 1 in 20 times my app (after launch) does not seems to 'beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents' and hence the ios remote defaults to the native music player. Because of this my app has been rejected (at an update, not initial release), the thing is I can never see it happen when the iPhone is plugged into mac and xcode only when running the app on the phone, below is my audio initialization routine.
Hope someone can help, thanks Mike.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self becomeFirstResponder];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
//Set the audio category of this app to playback.
NSError *setCategoryError = nil; [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
                                  setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryError];

if (setCategoryError)
{
    ShowMessageBox(@"Audio error", @"Category failed");
}

//Activate the audio session
NSError *activationError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError];

if (activationError) {
    ShowMessageBox(@"Audio error", @"Activate failed");
}

}
// And also

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```